# Odata $expand of property returns null

Tags: entity-framework, properties, odata, expand

I'm trying to get properties of an object through my odata **WCF** service, but when i use $expand on a particular property, it appears to be "null". However, in another property I have the Id of that object (using Entityframework) and there you can see the Id is NOT empty.

**The Model:**

```
[Table("Approval"), DataContract, IgnoreProperties("Status", "Id")]
public class Approval : BaseEntity
{
    ...

    [DataMember]
    public Guid? ApproverId { get; set; }
    [DataMember, ForeignKey("ApproverId")]
    public virtual User Approver { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual Request Request { get; set; }
}

[Table("Request"), DataContract, DataServiceKey("Id")]
public class Request : BaseEntity
{
    ...

    [DataMember]
    public Guid? LastModifiedById { get; set; }
    [DataMember, ForeignKey("LastModifiedById")]
    public virtual User LastModifiedBy { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual Approval Approval { get; set; }

    [DataMember, Required]
    public Guid AbsenteeId { get; set; }
    [DataMember, ForeignKey("AbsenteeId")]
    public virtual User Absentee { get; set; }

    [DataMember, Required]
    public Guid AbsenceTypeId { get; set; }
    [DataMember, ForeignKey("AbsenceTypeId")]
    public virtual AbsenceType AbsenceType { get; set; }
}
```

**The odata service call:**

```
http://<servername>/DataService.svc/Approvals?&$format=json&$expand=Request,Request/Absentee,Request/LastModifiedBy,Request/AbsenceType,Approver&$skip=0&$top=1
```

**The Returned Result:**

```
{
  "odata.metadata": "http://<servername>/DataService.svc/$metadata#Approvals",
  "value": [
    {
      "Approver": null,
      "Request": {
        "LastModifiedBy": null,
        "Absentee": null,
        "AbsenceType": null,
        ...
        "LastModifiedById": "6a1f8e79-99f5-e511-9444-0050568627d2",
        "AbsenteeId": "6a1f8e79-99f5-e511-9444-0050568627d2",
        "AbsenceTypeId": "fc7e8a5d-99f5-e511-9444-0050568627d2"
      },
      ...
      "ApproverId": null
    }
  ]
}
```

In this case, value -> Request -> LastModifiedBy/Absentee/AbsenceType should NOT be empty!!!!

Anyone who knows what I missed/did wrong?

Comment: Please post some sample code (controller methods, OData config, etc.) and expand your description of the problem.

Comment: Can you refer to the test code used EF to see where you missed? :) https://github.com/OData/WebApi/tree/master/OData/test/E2ETest/WebStack.QA.Test.OData/Aggregation